# No stained glass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I got some glass, and I put it in the usual order (8 around, dye in the middle) of the crafting table. But the output was simply blank, no stained glass. Any Idea? I'm on Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition.

Comment: Glass panes or blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft Pocket Edition and Windows 10 Edition do not yet have stained glass. You will need to use the normal PC Java Edition if you want to use stained glass.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition#Content